# How should you return *this with a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

See also: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382166/smart-pointers-this-considered-harmful)

The code below is obviously dangerous.  The question is: how do you do keep track of the reference to *this?

```
using namespace boost;

// MyClass Definition
class MyClass {

public:
   shared_ptr< OtherClass > createOtherClass() {
      return shared_ptr< OtherClass > OtherClass( this ); // baaad
   }
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
};

// OtherClass Definition
class OtherClass {

public:
   OtherClass( const *MyClass myClass );
   ~OtherClass();
};

// Call; pMyClass refcount = 1
shared_ptr< MyClass > pMyClass( new MyClass() );

// Call; pMyClass refcount = 1 => dangerous
pMyClass->createOtherClass();
```

I have the answer (posted below), I just want it to be on stackoverflow (where everyone can correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted down.. from the FAQ: It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question [..]

Comment: The downvote may well have been because the code you have posted in the question won't compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, the point was not to provide compilable code but, instead, to illustrate the point with unnecessary details elided.

Comment: It doesn't even illustraete the point. Unless you show what OtherClass does with the pointer in its constructor, the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key is to extend `enable_shared_from_this<T>` and use the `shared_from_this()` method to get a shared_ptr to `*this`

[For detailed information](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184402026)

```
using namespace boost;    

// MyClass Definition
class MyClass : public enable_shared_from_this< MyClass > {

public:
   shared_ptr< OtherClass> createOtherClass() {
      return shared_ptr< OtherClass > OtherClass( shared_from_this() );
   }
   MyClass();
   ~MyClass();
};

// OtherClass Definition
class OtherClass {

public:
   OtherClass( shared_ptr< const MyClass > myClass );
   ~OtherClass();
};

// Call; pMyClass refcount = 1
shared_ptr< MyClass > pMyClass( new MyClass() );

// Call; pMyClass refcount = 2
pMyClass->createOtherClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:
Your code does not compile!!

Your code is not designed in a way that it stops abuse/incorrect usage:

```
MyClass            x;
SharedPtr<MyClass> y = x.createOtherClass();
```

Now what?
This seems like a perfectly good use case!

Comment: Your 2nd point is right on.  Linked article says "keep in mind that the object you call shared_from_this on must be owned by a shared_ptr object."  Best to make ctor private and provide named constructor (static method) that returns shared_ptr<MyClass> to enforce correct creation.